# Adding input element dynamically to form and storing the value in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have to make a form which creates a button, clicking upon which a dynamic text field appears.

My javascript for this is:

```
function add() {

    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.style.borderRadius ="5px";
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("value", "ip2");
    element.setAttribute("name", "ip2");
    element.setAttribute("placeholder", "ip2"); 
    element.setAttribute("required", "true");
    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(element);

}
```

and I am using following code for the button and required container:

```
<form method="post" action="insert.php">
<INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)"/>

<span id="fooBar"></span>
</form>
```

Input field is fine. I only want to know how to take value from the dynamic input field and store it in the db.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can simply submit the form and use php in the backend to target the value by the `name` attr or you can use js to get the value via `class` or `id` and do a ajax request. Do you have code for a working db conn ?

Comment: Store it in the DB? You meann sending it to a server and store the values? You would need some backend language for that like PHP

Comment: yeah i have backend php file for recieving but problem is i am not getting the value through name attr using post method

Answer (score 0):

Once the fiels is addedd to fooBar, it is inside the form. If you submit the form via a submit button (see below HTML code) or via javascript `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();` you have to handle the results sent to the server with a script on the server, e.g. with PHP.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $_POST ); /* Show ALL given $_POST input */
echo '</pre>';
error_reporting(0);
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pnb");
if( !$conn ) {
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_error() );
}

if( isset( $_POST['ip2'] ) AND !empty( $_POST['ip2'] ) ) {
    $ip2 = $_POST['ip2'];
    mysqli_query( $conn, 'INSERT INTO records (ip) VALUES ("' . mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $ip2 ) . '")' );
    echo 'Row added!';
}
mysqli_close( $conn );
```

HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="insert.php">
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    <span id="fooBar"></span>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function add() {

    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.style.borderRadius ="5px";
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("value", "ip2");
    element.setAttribute("name", "ip2");
    element.setAttribute("placeholder", "ip2"); 
    element.setAttribute("required", "true");
    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(element);
}
</script>
```

**Note:** `document.forms[0].element.value` does not exist, hence I removed it from the code above. Also I added a submit button, to submit the form to the `insert.php` script on the server.

The above script will check if a post package with the name "ip2" is received. It than will setup a MySQLi connection to a database and insert the value in table "tablename". The above code should be placed in `insert.php`

Comment: insert.php file is like :
<?php 


error_reporting(0);
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pnb"); 
if (!$conn) { 
 die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
echo "connection failed" ; 
} 
//echo 'Connection OK'; mysql_close($conn);
$ip2=$_POST['ip2'];
$query="INSERT INTO `records`(`ip`) VALUES ('$ip2');
mysqli_query($conn,$query);

Comment: The code you placed in the comment, opens a MySQLi connection, than closes a MySQL connection!? that is rather impossible i think. I'll edit my answere to this code.

Comment: connection is fine the only problem is that the following part of the code is not working :  $ip2 = $_POST['ip2'];

Comment: Check if there is a value at all in $_POST['ip2']. Add `print_r( $_POST );` to the top of the script and see if ['ip2'] exists and has a value. If not, the problem is in the HTML code / submitting the form.

Comment: what type of problem could u please elaborate!!

Comment: added the HTML code. This code works for me. That is: once i click the add button, a new element is added (text field) with the value "ip2" and the name "ip2". Once I press the submit button, the value is sent to the server and printed by `print_r()`. It also is inserted in the database.

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['foo'])) {

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$item = $_POST['foo']

$sql = "INSERT INTO thetable (item)
VALUES ('$item')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo" value="foo">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Also if you are targeting an external file you should update the `action` attr on the form to the url of the file e.g. `action="target.php"`